# Is there a styleguide for developing SWT applications?

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, styling

I'm not a proficient GUI developer, and I have no talent for design. Is there a comprehensive style guide for developing SWT applications? I'm especially interested in standards for developing layouts, what margins and spacing between controls to use, font sizes and stuff like that.

Comment: If you build on top of RCP there are defaults set that are pretty standard.  You barely have to worry about that sort of stuff.

Comment: If there isn't there should be!  I'd really like to see something like that too.

Comment: @Alcon Thats not entirely true. For instance a TitleAreaDialog has a dialogArea which has no margins at all. If I put something on it (in my case a TabFolder), it just looks crappy. But I also don't know what size the margin should have. Just have a look at the eclipse search dialog, there is definitely a margin (and this is not automatically).

Answer (score 5):

There is Eclipse [User Interface guidelines](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines). Also see some UI walk troughs in Eclipse [User Interface Best Practices Working Group](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Best_Practices_Working_Group).